# Cannot fill the screen with UITableView with constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have UIViewController that contains an UIImageView  as background and a UITableView that is placed over the UITableView. I've used 4 constraints to make the UIImageView fill the screen for all devices (O top, O right, 0 bottom, 0 left). It seems to works. I've applied the same constraints to the UITableView, but it doesn't act the same:
[image]

It's really frustrating... Here are the constraints:

[image]

Comment: Are you setting the constraints in Interface Builder / Storyboard? or via code?

Comment: Using  Interface Builder / Storyboard !

Answer (score 0):

Place the UITableView on the screen and align it with all the edges of the device. Then just click the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" button and hit "Add Missing Constraints".

[image]

Take a look at what constraints it adds when you do that. That will give you a better idea of the right way to set the edges to match the screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will do that and give you a feedback. Thanks !!

Comment: I have tried but still not fitting the screen for all devices, for the 7 plus it's still like it is shown on my post.. I'll add the constraints

Comment: Adding the constraints like this works in a sample project I have created on a iPhone 7 plus simulator. You must be doing something a little off from what I instructed. Either way though those constraints will fix your issue.